# how can i count number of records in table where status = 1 using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have **1 table** named status with **3 conditions**, namely `completed`, `postponed`, and `canceled`. I want to change these 3 conditions into a number, for example `finish = 1`, `postponed` and `canceled = 0`. What I ask is how do I convert the data into a number in laravel (php)

Comment: you can create `const` in model

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that in a model Status and that the fields are stored as booleans you could do something like

```
class Status
{
    protected $casts = [
        'completed' => 'integer',
        'postponed' => 'integer',
        'canceled' => 'integer',
    ];
}
```

This will work simply because `(int) true` is `1` and `(int) false` is `0`. For a more general solution you could define accessors as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor